# Twitter users/search issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, twitter

I am trying to search users through new iOS Twitter framework by using following url ..
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/search.json?q=%@&page=2&per_page=20

The api says that maximum 20 persons will be searched per_page..
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/search

So i set the page=2 to fetch 40 persons but it is still fetching 20 persons.

Is this the bug in twitter framework or there is something else that i have to do..

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what query you run, you'll get 20 people back. The reason to set `page` is so that you can page through the results.

`page=1&per_page=20` returns the first 20 people.`page=2&per_page=20` returns the next 20 people. And so on.

Comment: Thanks Wayne. but how to implement it in iphone.
And isn't there any way to get >20 persons in a single request.

Comment: No, there isn't any way to get >20 people in a single request, that's just how it's defined.